# How to use Google Apps API with pinia?

Tags: google-apps-script, vuejs3, pinia

I am starting with pinia.vuejs and I want to use google.script.run functions in the store
Here is an example that fetches a page of persons

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'.
export const useMainStore = defineStore('mainStore',
    {
        state: () => {
            return {
                persons: [{}]
            }
        },
        actions: {
            fetchPersons() {
                console.log('fetching persons in store')
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(this.fetchPersonsSuccess).fetchPersons()
            },
            fetchPersonsSuccess(data) {
                console.log('receiving data in store')
                console.log(data)
                this.persons = data
            },
        }
    }
)
```

Up to now  this allows me to trigger the fetching from anywhere and using the result in a component's template
But how to use the withFailureHandler to display something if anything wrong happens, for example when I use another action to modify a spreadsheet?

Comment: Why not just  create `fetchPersonsFailure`?

Comment: You can check this documentation on how to use [withFailureHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#code.gs_1).

Comment: Hi everybody. Thank you for you comments. The trouble I have is as the failure handler has to be in the store, how to return the feedback from it to the component that triggers the action first? I will have a deeper look at the doc.